# order javascript array by grouping according to a property

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping

i'm using an array of json objects back from a search webservice to feed a jQuery.ui autocomplete where i use the [category system](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#categories) to group my objects according to their "family"

The algorithm uses a list where the groups are already ordered nicely, which i can't do at the moment so i'd like to organize the data on the client side. So for example if i have the following array:

```
var resultsArray = [
{"cat": "Category #1", "Id": "10"},
{"cat": "Category #2", "Id": "28"},
{"cat": "Category #1", "Id": "11"},
{"cat": "Category #2", "Id": "21"},
{"cat": "Category #1", "Id": "13"}
];
```

i'd like to call a method on resultsArray so i get back

```
resultsArray = [
{"cat": "Category #1", "Id": "10"},
{"cat": "Category #1", "Id": "11"},
{"cat": "Category #1", "Id": "13"},
{"cat": "Category #2", "Id": "28"},
{"cat": "Category #2", "Id": "21"}
];
```

grouping by the cat property while retaining the existing order.

At first i tried to use the sort method on the array, by returning the positions in the array where the value i'm trying to group by would be found (assume acs.groupBy contains the name of the grouping property:

```
items.sort(function(a, b) {
    var aValue = a[acs.groupBy],
    bValue = b[acs.groupBy];
    var indexOfAValue = 0; // should be sthing like items.indexWhere(item[acs.groupBy] === aValue)
    var indexOfBValue = 0; // same thing
    return indexOfAValue - indexOfBValue;
});
```

with indexOfAValue would be the first position in the array where the grouping property for A is found, but i can't find a method to get and cache this value simply (array's indexOf matches a whole object). Any idea to get this?

---

**EDIT**

Looks like i gave the wrong example :)
I don't want to sort the categories. If Category #2 happens before Category #1, i want to retain this info so

```
var resultsArray = [
    {"cat": "Category #3", "Id": "39"},
    {"cat": "Category #2", "Id": "28"},
    {"cat": "Category #1", "Id": "11"},
    {"cat": "Category #2", "Id": "21"},
    {"cat": "Category #1", "Id": "18"}
]
```

would become (note that even though i grouped the items according to their category, i didn't change the order in which the categories occur, and i didn't change the items order inside the groups according to their id either)

```
var resultsArray = [
    {"cat": "Category #3", "Id": "39"},
    {"cat": "Category #2", "Id": "28"},
    {"cat": "Category #2", "Id": "21"},
    {"cat": "Category #1", "Id": "11"},
    {"cat": "Category #1", "Id": "18"}
]
```

That's why i was trying to order by indexOf(category) in my sample above

Comment: I would highly recommend looking at some of Underscore's array functionality: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, your `sort` function doesn't need to be to complex:

```
function group(array) {
    var i, categories = {};
    /* Build a map of categories and minimum indices: */
    for (i = 0; i < resultsArray.length; i++) {
        if (!categories[resultsArray[i].cat]) {
            categories[resultsArray[i].cat] = i;
        }
    }

    /* Sort the array using the minimum index: */
    return resultsArray.sort(function(one, other) {
        return categories[one.cat] - categories[other.cat];
    });
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/dn2U5/

This should get you started. Unfortunately the function loops through the array twice (which obviously is not optimal).

Comment: @samy: I have a preliminary solution. It isn't optimal but hopefully it will get you started. Let me know what you think!

Comment: i arrived at the same result: http://jsfiddle.net/b7cNc/3/ I was hoping there would be a way to do it in one go but i couldn't find one. Your answer is correct :)

Comment: this won't keep the original order in some browsers

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're just looking for a normal stable sort?  The native JS sort is stable in most browsers (every modern browser for the last 2 years or so), so simply:

```
items.sort( function( a, b ){
    return a.Id - b.Id;
} );
```

will usually work, but it's not stable in *all* browsers, so to make it so, do something like:

```
for( var i=0... ){
   items[i].index = i;
}
items.sort( function( a, b ){
    return ( a.Id != b.Id ) ? ( a.Id - b.Id ) : ( a.index - b.index );
}
```

which sorts by the Id then the original order.

Comment: I'm going to try and learn about this stable sort. I'll be back asap with results :)

Comment: It just means that it keeps the original order when the values are the same

Comment: your method was on the right track (ie keep an index of the different items) but i need apparently a way to keep track of the original indices in the list (through the use of an hashtable for example). Thank you though for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: that does keep track of the original indicies

Comment: i've tried to implement your solution http://jsfiddle.net/b7cNc/5/ but apparently i'm not understanding it correctly. From what you can see the sort doesn't produce the correct output.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't understand the original requirement correctly, sorry :)  You need to actually combine the two answers to get something that fully works.  You need to track the categories as in Andrew's answer _and_ track the original index as in my answer.  Then use my basic sort code, except compare `category` then `index`.  If you do _not_ do this, you're going to get out-of-order `Id`s in many older browsers

Comment: no problem, i thought for a moment that the "stable sort" meant you could sort some subset of the array. However i'd be interested to know what browsers could pose a problem; either i'll have to direct them to another sorting method, or i'll want a catchall algorithm

Comment: It's only older browsers AFAIK, but not _that_ old.  Chrome had an unstable sort until _around_ V10, FF until 3.something, Safari 3, Opera 10.  I'm not _positive_ on those numbers, but they're close.  Ironically this is the one place where IE prevails, it's been stable since at least 5.5, possibly always.

Comment: ok, thanks, i'll try to find a version of these browsers, or at least a version of their javascript engine is possible: perhaps there are places on the web that allow you to test your js against various js engines